# PHP - trying to define two color stops for a gradient background area where users can select both colors with a color picker

Tags: php, wordpress, gradient

PHP - trying to define two color stops for a gradient background to be applied to a single CSS selector. I need them to be individually selected by the user (via a color picker).

I've been defining the background color with PHP (named: $color_gradient & returning: '#f7f7f7'; as the default for users to start with) so the user can choose the base color of the gradient (via PHP), and then I have color-to-alpha gradient overlays set in the css (so the background color chosen by users fades to a black or white ending color) to get an effect closest to what I'm trying to accomplish, but it is still rather limiting to whatever color I've set in the CSS for the overlay, and I don't want users to have to edit the color codes in the css file - I'd rather just have PHP handle it so that the user can define both colors of the gradient instead of just the one.

```
function theme_customizer_get_default_gradient_color() {
    return '#f7f7f7';
}

$color_gradient = get_theme_mod( 'theme_gradient_color', 
theme_customizer_get_default_gradient_color() );

    $css .= ( theme_customizer_get_default_gradient_color() !== $color_gradient ) ? 
sprintf( '      
    .nav-primary,
    .site-footer {
        background-color: %1$s;
    }
    ', $color_gradient ) : '';

if ( theme_customizer_get_default_gradient_color() !== $color_gradient
```

Is there a way to define something like "from left" & "from right" in HEX or RGB colors, for say an area's background color, so that the two colors defined in PHP are treated as each half of the gradient and that the user can select each color separately and they still blend together?

Or is there a way to have the PHP handle the overlay (instead of having it handled in CSS) that will remain an alpha-to-color item rather than being changed to a solid color once the user selects a new color? (I'm concerned about the transparency getting overridden once the user changes to a color other than the default.)

I'm not looking for anyone to code out this for me; I just need a nudge in some direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS, gradients use background-image. Try defining variables in your function for each color and the direction; for example:

```
background-image: linear-gradient( to right, $color1, $color2 );
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Comment: That might work. I'll play with the code a bit tonight & see if it can work some magic. Thanks.

Comment: Good luck; let me know how it works out and if I can be of any more help.

Comment: Ok, I had to put this aside for a couple weeks, but finally am trying to get this fully functional. At this point I've got the customize.php file setting the two colors that a user chooses, however, because they are targeting the same css the 2nd color just overrides the first, which is expected since I don't have any further directions applied on how I want the code to blend the two colors. So my next step is placement of the snippet you've suggested. Wherever I put it, it just gets ignored most of the time (unless I white-screen it).